# Use Pipenv to build and publish a Python package

Tags: python, pipenv

Context: I'm setting up a new Python project and decided to give [PEP-517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) and [PEP-518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) ("build systems") a whirl, instead of my usual `setup.py`-plus-a-bunch-of-shell-scripts configuration. My requirements are: dependency management and being able to create a Python package and publish it to PyPI. I decided to give [Pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) a chance.

Problem: I cannot find any information about how to create a Python package when using `Pipenv` to manage the dependencies. It appears that `Pipenv` doesn't provide means for that. So, does it mean that in addition to the `Pipfile` I still need to create a `setup.py`? What is the point of having the `Pipfile` then? Or is it possible to "snapshot" a `Pipenv` into a `setup.py` for example? If so, how do I manage other attributes (package description, author, project URL, etc.) in this case?

To avoid any confusion, my question is not to find a library or a tool, but about how to accompilsh a specific task - build and publish a Python package - in the Python project with dependency management based on `Pipenv`.

Answer (score 5):

Pipenv doesn't allow you to publish a package as you may hope. It is used for development, and for the publishing step you will still need a `setup.py` file. There's some good news, you can use `pipenv-setup` to sync your pipenv packages without any manual editing (`pipenv-setup sync --dev`).

An alternative to `Pipenv` that also allows you to publish your project is `Poetry`: it has a simple `poetry publish` command that does just that. It is also based on `pyproject.toml`, which is being pushed as a replacement for `setup.py`

Comment: how you would compare pipenv vs poetry ?

Comment: From my use of the both, I can say that pipenv can be used with more utility pacakges, like versioneer for app versioning, or pipenv-setup for syncing setup.py to the Pipfile. Poetry, being a newer project, lacks a bunch of them, but on the other hand groups everything in pyproject.toml. In a world where every pacakge could be configured using only one .toml file I would generally recommend poetry. Given that it's not still a broadly-adopted approach, you will still need a separate setup.cfg file which is sub-optimal. At the moment I use pipenv, but I keep making poetry projects every now and

Comment: then to see how the development goes. I have good expectations for it and wouldn't be surprised to see it gain popularity

Comment: I tried pip-tools  `pip-compile --upgrade --build-isolation --generate-hashes --output-file requirements/main.txt requirements/main.in` then `pip install -r requirements/main.txt`... works quite well.

Comment: poetry is the way to go. Having the same dependency data in multiple places - Pipfile, setup.py, and pyproject.toml - is just asking for trouble.